# Find matched data from object in mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I want to get all matched data from an object but I am getting an empty array.

Here is the location table:

```
const locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    location: {
      name: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        lowercase: true,
      },
      subLocation: [String],
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

and it is embedded in route table:

```
const routeSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    location: {
      from: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Location",
        required: true,
      },
      to: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Location",
        required: true,
      },
    },
    busId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Bus",
      required: true,
    },
    date: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    departureTime: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    arrivalTime: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

Now I am running query to get the matched data from route table but I am getting an empty array.
`http://127.0.0.1:3000/trips?from=6295871d69217e9c28cf7f19&to=6295874869217e9c28cf7f1c&date=2022-06-02`
here is the query :

```
router.get("/trips", async (req, res) => {
  if (!req.query.from || !req.query.to || !req.query.date) {
    return res.send({
      error: "Please enter the data to get the trip",
    });
  }
  const { from, to, date } = req.query;

  const routes = await Route.find({
    from,
    to,
    date,
  });
```

**Another Question:**
I am passing an Id as a value now I want to pass value as a sting like this: `from=Mumbai&to=Ahmedabad&date=2022-06-02`.
How to do that? because whenever I do that I am getting a casting error

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/and/

Comment: @drpzet yes I did that and it is working but when I mess up the from and to's Id value it is still showing the results like(from=6295871d69217e9c28cf7f19 to from=fdu5456g7a).

Comment: For your second question also `lowercase: true` but you are providing `Mumbai`. Does that make any change if you try with `mumbai`?

Comment: @smilyface no it is not working it is showing error CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "mumbai" (type string) at path "location.to" for model "Route"

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change the location schema to have from and to locations separately like below.

```
const locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    fromLocation: {
      name: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        lowercase: true,
      },
      subLocation: [String],
    },
    toLocation: {
      name: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        lowercase: true,
      },
      subLocation: [String],
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

Thus the route schema should look like this

```
 const routeSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
      {
        location: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Location",
            required: true,
        },
            date: {
            type:String,
            required: true
        },
....
....
```

And then do something like this...

```
let locations = await Location.find({
    'fromLocation.name': from,
    'toLocation.name': to,
  });
```

After that

```
  const ids = locations.map(location => location._id)
 
  const routes = await Route.find({$and: [{location : {$in: ids}},{date}]});
  const route = routes.find(()=>{
    return ([{ date }, { routes }])
  });
```

Comment: I can not add from and to location in the location model

Comment: And that was the approach that I had taken earlier

Comment: @hrishikeshpathak , but this model should work, right?

Comment: yes, this model is working but there is a problem in this model

Comment: @hrishikeshpathak, can you explain ? If we can fix that, it will be easy for you. We will help!

Comment: Do you know Hindi because I am not very proficient in English. I can explain in Hindi

Comment: Yes, go ahead (but may be not suggested in here). But go ahead..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245197/discussion-between-hrishikesh-pathak-and-smilyface).